# CookieJars obtaining all cookies, nodeJS using request-promise

Tags: node.js, cookies, jar, request, request-promise

I am struggling to successfully make a request using `request-promise` npm on a site that requires a cookie to view or for the request to be successful.

Henceforth, I have looked into cookieJars in order to store all those that are given in the repsonse after the request has been done.

```
const rp = require("request-promise")
var cookieJar = rp.jar()
function grabcfToken(){
let token  = ""
let options = {
    url : 'https://www.off---white.com/en/GB',
    method: "GET",
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
    resolveWithFullResponse : true
}

rp(options)
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    }) 
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
```

}

Can someone tell me why the request isn't successfully going through? How do I apply the cookies that I initially get before being timed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
const rp = require("request-promise")
var cookieJar = rp.jar()
function grabcfToken(){
let token  = ""
let options = {
    url : 'https://www.off---white.com/en/GB',
    method: "GET",
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
    resolveWithFullResponse : true,       
   jar: cookieJar
}

rp(options)
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    }) 
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

If you're asking about including your jar which you filled with the cookies from the request to be sent to across you have to add **jar: cookiejar** as pasrt of your options object before sending it.